# googleplayservices Locationclient works in offline mode

Tags: android, location-client

I am using a location client in offline mode.

The app is supposed to fetch the location every 10 secs. If the wifi or mobile data is on, will it fetch the location using the mobile data? 
I don't want the user to be paid for every 10 secs just for fetching the location by using mobile data.

If GPS mobile data is also on, then from which method will the app fetch the location?

my goal is to fetch the location using location client every 10 secs without making paid by the user..

EDIT: can anyone just tell me does google play services location-client uses internet when mobile data is on?

Any insight knowledge is appreciable

Thanks

Comment: Just use GPS to access the location and not other mediums.

Answer (score 0):

Arrived at your question from another search.  Just to let you know if haven't come across it by now.

No, the user won't be charged for mobile data. Use of internet is not necessary.

`LocationClient` from `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient` will not use any `Internet` connections to retrieve the `location`.

However it is the implementation of location retrieval from `GooglePlayServices` package of the `SDK` uses the `FusedProvider`  that needs to use/access the `WiFi` services with `GPS` and what is available to retrieve the `location`.

For some O.S. versions, this part is included under `Settings` for WiFi-use related to retrieval of location.